# Viewing initial data source and filtering with RxSwift using MVVM

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm starting out with RxSwift and trying to get a simple example of filtering a data source with a UISearchController working.

I have the basic setup of a UISearchController wired into a UITableViewController. Using MVVM I also have a basic view model setup that will drive the table.

```
self.viewModel.searchText.accept(searchController.searchBar.text ?? "")
```

```
viewModel.listItems.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "ItemCell")) { row, item, cell in
    cell.textLabel!.text = item.name
}
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

View Model

```
class ListViewModel {

    private let sourceItems: BehaviorRelay<[ListItem]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [
            ListItem(name: "abc"),
            ListItem(name: "def"),
            ListItem(name: "ghi"),
            ListItem(name: "jkl"),
            ListItem(name: "mno")
        ])

    let searchText = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
    var listItems: Observable<[ListItem]> = Observable.just([])

    init() {
        listItems = sourceItems.asObservable()
    }

}
```

I can add in the search filtering and this works such that only the values matching the filter string will show

```
let searchObservable = searchText
    .throttle(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .filter { query in
        return query.count > 2
    }
    .share(replay: 1)

listItems = Observable.combineLatest(sourceItems.asObservable(), searchObservable) { items, query in
        return items.filter({ item in
            item.name.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())
        })
    }
```

However, this will not show any values until the filter is matched. What I am trying to do is initially show all the values and then only show the filtered values.  I'm not quite sure how to populate the `listItems` when the `searchText` changes but is empty or events are filtered out.

Comment: how do you changing your searchText?

Comment: have you tried making `sourceItems` of type ReplaySubject? ReplaySubject<[ListItem]>.create(bufferSize: 1)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to subscribe for changes, instead of

```
listItems = Observable.combineLatest(sourceItems.asObservable(), searchObservable) { items, query in
    return items.filter({ item in
        item.name.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())
    })
}
```

should be

```
        Observable.combineLatest(sourceItems.asObservable(), searchObservable) { items, query in
        return items.filter({ item in
            item.name.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())
        })
        }.subscribe(onNext: { resultArray in
            print(resultArray) // here you can change your listItems
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

this is how to change searchText `searchText.accept("123")`

UPDATED:

to handle any searchBar updates you should implement serachBar.rx
Here is some example how to

```
 import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class ListItem: NSObject {

    var name: String = ""

    public init(name str: String) {
        super.init()
        name = str
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    private let sourceItems: BehaviorRelay<[ListItem]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [
        ListItem(name: "abc"),
        ListItem(name: "def"),
        ListItem(name: "ghi"),
        ListItem(name: "jkl"),
        ListItem(name: "mno")
        ])

    let searchText = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
    var listItems: Observable<[ListItem]> = Observable.just([])
    var disposeBag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addSearchBarObserver()
        listItems = sourceItems.asObservable()
        Observable.combineLatest(sourceItems.asObservable(), searchText) { items, query in
            return items.filter({ item in
                item.name.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())
            })
            }.subscribe(onNext: { resultArray in
                print(resultArray)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func addSearchBarObserver() {
        searchBar
            .rx
            .text
            .orEmpty
            .debounce(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe { [weak self] query in
                guard
                    let query = query.element else { return }
                self?.searchText.accept(query)
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work, I have the same as the existing behaviour i.e. it starts with a blank `listItem`.  

The `searchText` is being set using `self.viewModel.searchText.accept(searchController.searchBar.text ?? "")` in the UITableViewController.

I think the issue is that the `combineLatest` isn't getting any events when it starts or when the search bar is emptied, but I'm not sure how to make it do what I need

Comment: I updated answer with full code example, ask if smth is unclear

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunately its still not quite there. When the controller loads for the first time or when the search box is emptied, the table is empty. Is there a way to display the full list on load and when the search bar is empty?

Comment: Thanks for your help, managed to tweak your answer to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

- my approach will be the following
- create such observable class as below

```
import Foundation

class Observable<Generic> {

    var value: Generic {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.valueChanged?(self.value)
            }
        }
    }

    private var valueChanged: ((Generic) -> Void)?

    init(_ value: Generic) {
        self.value = value
    }

    /// Add closure as an observer and trigger the closure imeediately if fireNow = true
    func addObserver(fireNow: Bool = true, _ onChange: ((Generic) -> Void)?) {
        valueChanged = onChange
        if fireNow {
            onChange?(value)
        }
    }

    func removeObserver() {
        valueChanged = nil
    }

}
```

- have in your VM the original list
- create different filtered list as below

```
var cellViewModels: Observable<[/* your model */]?>
```

- have the search bar delegate method in the View as below - remember it will vary depending on your implementation -

```
class TradeDealsViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    // Mark :- IB Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private var viewModel: ViewModel /* your VM */?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        viewModel = TradeDealsViewModel()
        bindViewLiveData()
    }

    private func bindViewLiveData(){
        viewModel?.cellViewModels.addObserver({ [weak self] (responsee) in
            self?.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        /* do your filtration logic here */
    }

}
```

- note that this solution does not use RxSwift it uses only foundation

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was looking for an RxSwift solution

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to @AlexandrKolesnik I managed to tweak his answer and get it working:

```swift
class ListViewModel {

    private let sourceItems: BehaviorRelay<[ListItem]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [
        ListItem(name: "abc"),
        ListItem(name: "def"),
        ListItem(name: "ghi"),
        ListItem(name: "jkl"),
        ListItem(name: "mno"),
        ListItem(name: "abcdef")
    ])

    private var filteredItems: BehaviorRelay<[ListItem]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [])

    let searchText = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
    var listItems: Observable<[ListItem]> {
        return filteredItems.asObservable()
    }

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init() {
        searchText
            .throttle(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe({ [unowned self] event in

                guard let query = event.element, !query.isEmpty  else {
                    self.filteredItems.accept(self.sourceItems.value)
                    return
                }

                self.filteredItems.accept(
                    self.sourceItems.value.filter {
                        $0.name.lowercased().contains(query.lowercased())
                    }
                )

            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

}
```